# Is "of the" interchangeable for "to" in this context?

Tags: prepositions

headline-style text:

"Senator Chuck Schumer’s decision to try for a bipartisan compromise on new gun laws is a test of the Senate — and of democracy itself."

the "test of the Senate" part seems to mean "test to Senate" is that so?
if so, how to know in which case can I use "of the" to mean "to"??

Comment: "...a test **to** the Senate" doesn't really make sense.  When we say "X is a test of Y", it means that Y is being tested by X.  I can't think of a way to phrase it with "to".

Comment: @stangdon, maybe it is tied to idiomatic issue, when I say: "new gun laws is a TO Senate" I immediately think of new gun laws represents a teste TO the senate, from the semathic point of view. Make any sense to you?

Comment: No, we just don't use the preposition *to* with "test".  The choice of prepositions is often very arbitrary.  You might be seeing sentences like "He presented a test to the class", but in that sentence, *to* actually goes with *present*, not *test*.

Comment: @stangdon, can we call that an idiomatic issue? :)

Comment: I guess you could call it idiomatic.  There often isn't much reason to why we use one preposition or another; you just have to learn which one is common.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "new gun laws is a TO Senate": that doesn't make sense. I'm guessing you left out the word _test_, but it still doesn't make sense. _Test_ doesn't take _to_, in any sense.

Answer (score 0):

One of our experts could answer this better than I will.

- Concept #1: "Test" is a noun, used as a noun, and represents either a physical object or a specific event ("I will take the test" or "The teacher handed me the test").
- Concept #2: "Test" is a verb, but it can be used as a noun (where are the experts!), and represents an *action.* ("My limits will be tested" vs. "A test of my limits").

The word "test" in your example is using Concept #2, and that's why the preposition "to" cannot be used. You can hand a physical object "to someone." But you can't hand an *action* to someone.

**The preposition "of" identifies a relationship**

These both use Concept #2. It sounds like the noun "test" (describing an action) is the same as the noun "test" (describing an object). But it isn't.

> It is a test of his strength.

"Strength" identifies what is being tested: an attribute.

> It is a test of the Senate.

"Senate" identifies what is being tested: an organization.

**The preposition "to" indicates motion or a direction of travel**

> Hand the test to me.

This is Concept #1. We are not told what is being tested (the verb). We only know that there is an object called a "test" (the noun).

**Finally, the infinitive "to *verb*"**

To avoid future confusion, there is a use of the word "to" that is different from its use as a preposition. In this case, it is part of an infinitive, which means it's part of a verb clause that modifies "test."

> It is a test *to know* his limits.

In this case, the infinitive "to know" can be replaced with the preposition "of."

> It is a test *of* his limits.